Unable to set up email clients with IMAP - on multiple emails and systems
I'm having trouble fixing my email client setups - it appears the connection keeps getting rejected by the server.
I have an (ollld) arcor.de email address, that had been synced via IMAP to both thunderbird on my PC (running Linux Mint) and Bluemail on my Android.
Both stopped working a couple weeks ago. Looking up the settings, I find that the responsible servers are now imap.vodafonemail.de and smtp.vodafonemail.de - cool, I just update them, right? Nope - I get, on Bluemail, "Cannot connect to server", and on Thunderbird "unable to log in at server" and "Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account" when I tried to set it up again from scratch.
I checked the login credentials and server settings a million times - for reference,

imap.vodafonemail.de port 993 and
smtp.vodafonemail.de port 465.

and tested all different options for connection protocols and authentication methods - it can't connect to the server.
I can log into the web portal just fine, so I know my login and internet connection are good.
When I connect my phone to mobile data or a different wifi, the problem persists, so we can rule out an issue with my modem or the like.
I tried using the Claws mail client, which gives me the error
Connecting to IMAP server: imap.vodafonemail.de:993...
*** SSL/TLS handshake failed

I can ping the imap server.
Testing the port like so
openssl s_client -connect imap.vodafonemail.de:993 gives me
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 322 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)

so it seems the server refuses the connection? Not sure what to make of it.
Now here's where it gets too weird for me -

I set up a new proton.me email address and syncing with Thunderbird - I get "Thunderbird  -failed to find the settings for your email account" for this one as well!
the vodafonemail POP3 server works! It connects and downloads my emails. But both IMAP and SMTP fail.

I am officially out of ideas. Please help.

Do you get anything if you connect to the server on TLS port but without TLS (e.g. using telnet or netcat)? What happens if you make an IMAP STARTTLS connection to port 143?

Have you tried both with and without VPN? It could be the server refuses connections from some locales.

@grawity_u1686
With telnet I get:
telnet imap.vodafonemail.de 993
Trying 2.207.150.230...
Connected to imap.vodafonemail.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
That's what it's supposed to be, right?
